# Grid View with dynamic column and row with fit to screen(without scrolling)

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

i have a gridview designed with the help of [this](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-gridview-example/) example.

I am able to display the grid view without any issues but the problem is i have to make to work in both portrait and landscape, in portrait it will be 3 rows and 2 columns with fixed height without any scrolling and in lanscape mode it will be 2 rows and 3 columns without any scrolling, challenge here is currently there are 6 items in my gridview, suppose tomorrow if i change that to 8 or 4 items it should work without scrolling in both orientation and also should work for both mobiles and tablets.

i tried searching a lot and got this and tried it which will give me height and width of device and i tried decrementing the `header(40dp)` value and `footer(40dp)` with the height and width but not working.

```
Display mDisplay= activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width= mDisplay.getWidth();
int Height= mDisplay.getHeight();
```

here is how my layout looks like :

```
header

gridview //items may change from 6 ,4,8 but it should fit to this area with scrolling

footer
```

please help i am stuck from long time.

Answer (score 1):

Dear you know about apply height and width dynamic  then  apply this height and width of **image view of gridview runtime.**

it`s work dear and where landscape then **interchange width and height.**

Try this.

**Interchange Height and width **

```
WindowManager winManager = (WindowManager) myContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        screenWidth = winManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        screenHeight = winManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

int temp=screenWidth;
screenWidth=screenHeight;
screenHeight=temp;
```

Comment: my gridview item has a image view and text view both i have given as wrap content, can you please help me how is that?, i have also interchanged the width to height and height to width .